# Moving a charge with constant velocity

Tags: forces, electrostatics, charge, velocity

How can we make a positive test charge move with a constant velocity from infinity if the source charge is positive? I know that when a particle moves with a constant velocity velocity the net force on it is zero so how will the charge move with a constant velocity from rest

Answer (score 3):

You have to apply *another* force that is always equal and opposite to the repulsive force from the source charge!

In practice this would be difficult to do, but I imagine you are trying to understand the definition of *electric potential*, so you won't ever have to apply such a force. You can, though, *imagine* yourself pulling the test charge towards the source charge using an insulating thread, and checking all the time that the test charge isn't accelerating.

Comment: I think we should give more force initially to make it move either it would be in an equilibrium position in rest in infinity.

Comment: Agreed. But this initial force can be made as small as we like if we're prepared to move the charge extremely slowly!

Answer (score 1):

The particle can't move at a constant velocity from rest. Changing from "at rest" to a velocity defines an acceleration. What you could do is apply a force for a very short period of time and then remove the force. The test charge will obtain a velocity due to the force, but after the force is removed the particle moves with that constant velocity. How you remove the force is a different problem altogether.