# How a particle move with a constant velocity from rest?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, velocity

How can a particle move with a constant velocity from rest? I know that the net force on a particle that moves with a constant velocity is zero, so how will it move from rest with a constant velocity if the net force is zero

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving a charge with constant velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428132/moving-a-charge-with-constant-velocity)

Comment: @StephenG I don't think it's a duplicate. They're both by the same author; looks like the OP was confused about the answers there and tried to ask a separate question about that. Except this question's a bit unclear... I can't really tell what he's asking.

Answer (score 1):

For a body to attain a constant velocity starting from zero, **at least** for a certain time interval a non-zero external force must act on the body in order to accelerate the body from zero velocity to the constant velocity that you are referring to. Once it attains a certain velocity and all the external forces becomes zero, it will continue to move with that certain velocity.